# VB SaveFileDialog returns "No items match your search." for a specific folder filtering for .txt for example

Tags: vb.net

VB SaveFileDialog returns "No items match your search." for a specific folder filtering for .txt for example. But the open file dialog for other applications eg. Notepad will show all .txt files.

Comment: how much help do you expect to get with without a single byte of  code?

Comment: Please **show us your code**. @Plutonix Please *[be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior)*.

Comment: *"I do **not** want to show you **my precious**!"* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not posting any code, after finding the solution I can see it was important. 
Found a solution

```
' This does not work i.e. dialog returns "No items match your search."
FileDialog1.Filter = ""
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|C/C++|*.cpp;*.c;*.h;*.rc"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|CSharp|*.cs"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|CSS|*.css"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|eRuby|*.erb;*.rhtml"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|Java|*.java"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|JavaScript|*.js"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|JSP|*.jsp"

' This solves the problem, dialog shows files with the selected file extension(s)
SaveFileDialog1.Filter = ""
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|C/C++ (*.cpp;*.c;*.h;*.rc)|*.cpp;*.c;*.h;*.rc"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|CSharp (*.cs)|*.cs"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|CSS (*.css)|*.css"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|eRuby (*.erb;*.rhtml)|*.erb;*.rhtml"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|Java (*.java)|*.java"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|JavaScript (*.js)|*.js"
SaveFileDialog1.Filter += "|JSP (*.jsp)|*.jsp"
```

Just for interest sake, if the search uses the the first part of the parameter e.g. 
   CSS (*.css) what is the purpose of the second part of the parameter (the file extensions after the "|" delimiter) ?